# How do I make this multi-login take me to another html within my code? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I started a beginners project to learn more about JS with a multiuser ATM.

Things I'm trying to do:

1. 3 Users that have password and balance when they log in
2. The login page should redirect you to the ATM site, and it will show you your balance in a pre-built calculator

I want to make the ATM work too but I first need to get the login right
Here is my code

```js
// Login: Try limit, page change, usernames
let entryCount = 1;
let entryLimit = 3;

let users = [
    { name: "Emilio", password: "a", balance: 1000 },
    { name: "Andrea", password: "b", balance: 20000 },
    { name: "Hugo", password: "c", balance: 300000 },
];

let mainScreen = document.getElementById('login-page')
let conctentAccountScreen = document.createTextNode("account screen")
let accountScreen = document.createElement("span").setAttribute("id", "accountScreen")

// Login
let button = document.getElementById ('login');

button.onclick = function() {
    let username = document.getElementById('user').value; 
    let password = document.getElementById('pass').value;

    userExists = false
    correctPassword = false
    saldoExists = false

    for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if (username == users[i].username && password == users[i].password) {
            userExists = true
            correctPassword = true
            saldoExists = true
            window.location.href = "atm.html"
        } else{
            alert('Try again bro')
        }
        if (entryCount < entryLimit)  {
            entryCount++
            alert('Username or Password are incorrect, please try again')
            } else {
                alert('You exceeded the number of tries')
                window.location.href = "index.html"
        }
    }
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);

.login-page {
width: 360px;
padding: 8% 0 0;
margin: auto;
}
.form {
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
background: #FFFFFF;
max-width: 360px;
margin: 0 auto 100px;
padding: 45px;
text-align: center;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.form input {
font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
outline: 0;
background: #f2f2f2;
width: 100%;
border: 0;
margin: 0 0 15px;
padding: 15px;
box-sizing: border-box;font-size: 14px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;font-size: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.form button {
font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
outline: 0;
background: #fce205;
width: 100%;
border: 0;
padding: 15px;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 14px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
transition: all 0.3 ease;
cursor: pointer;
}
.form button:hover,.form button:active,.form button:focus {
background: #ffbf00;
}
.form .message {
margin: 15px 0 0;
color: #b3b3b3;
font-size: 12px;
}
.form .message a {
color: #4CAF50;
text-decoration: none;
}
.form .register-form {
display: none;
}
.container {
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
max-width: 300px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:before, .container:after {
content: "";
display: block;
clear: both;
}
.container .info {
margin: 50px auto;
text-align: center;
}
.container .info h1 {
margin: 0 0 15px;
padding: 0;
font-size: 36px;
font-weight: 300;color: #1a1a1a;

.container .info span {
color: #4d4d4d;
font-size: 12px;
}
.container .info span a {
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
}
.container .info span .fa {
color: #EF3B3A;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                                        <!-- CSS with Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

    <title>ATM</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="login-page">
        <div class="form">
            <h1>Welcome back to your bank, please log in.</h1>
        <form class="login-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="username" id="user">
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="pass">
            <button id="login" type="button">login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
                                        <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if this is what you need, but to change the html page via Javascript you can simply do:

```
location.href = '/something.html';
```

Or to an external site like this:

```
location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
```

Also your code will alert repeatedly as you are doing `alert('Try again bro')` for EVERY user in the `users` array... also where is `userExists`, `correctPassword` and `saldoExists` being declarated?

Now this seems a better way of handling if user and password exists, dunno if it's what you're trying tho:

```
button.onclick = function() {
    let username = document.getElementById('user').value; 
    let password = document.getElementById('pass').value;

    const user = user.find(x => username == x.username && password == x.password);
    
    if (user) {
        // Do whataver you want if user is found.
        location.href = "atm.html"
    } else {
        // Do whataver you want if user is NOT found.
        alert('Try again bro');
    }
}
```

And as so for last observation, you might like to import your Javascript file at the end of the body in the html (more information about why here: https://hackinbits.com/interview-questions/html/why-script-tags-should-be-placed-at-the-end-of-body-tag) **(this is also potentially causing the error you commented)**

Comment: I'm getting an error concerning the DOM it says

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick')

Comment: ok, seems `let button = document.getElementById ('login');` is not getting the DOM element... You sure you have not modified the html or the js you've posted here? not having that issue using it.

Comment: I don't get why, the ID of the button is "login" and nah fam, this is the exact code I have.

Comment: hm... would you please try creating the function with a name and adding `onclick="yourFunction()"` to the button in the html? Also added a modified version of the function... you can easily do what you're manually doing with a `for`, more simple and cleaner with `find`

Comment: Good, I don't have that error anymore, but it still does nothing.

Comment: Bro es muy complicado que te ayude asi. A que te refieres con que no hace nada? Entra en la funcion? probaste loggear algo para asegurarte? Que estas haciendo ahorita en la funcion?

Comment: Una disculpa, el login no hace nada, introduzco la info y nomas no me muestra los alerts ni pasa a la siguiente página

Comment: Esta bien. Estas usando la funcion que pase en la respuesta o la tuya previa? Podrias poner un `console.log('hola!')` al principio de la funcion asociada al boton para corroborar que el flujo sea correcto?

Comment: Asi es, ahora el onclick está en el HTML y a la función le asigné un nombre 

No pinta la consola ahora, la puse asi:

function loginButton() {
    console.log ('Hola!')
}

Comment: Ok, te diria si podes probar con la siguiente linea: `document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click", () => { console.log("hola!"); }, false);`. A su vez, importando el archivo javascript **AL FINAL** del body, no en el header. Haciendolo de esta forma, se deberia de printear en consola `"hola!"`

Comment: Ya pinto el hola

Comment: Ya. entonces puedes cambiar la funcion que printea el hola (si usaste el codigo del anterior comentario, seria `{ console.log("hola!"); }`) por la funcion que tu quieras. Puedes usar por ejemplo la que deje en la respuesta la cual va a buscar si el usuario existe en la lista y tiene esa contraseña; Si la tiene, se va a atm.html, si no la tiene, alerta `try again bro`

Comment: ¿Entonces me dices que quite el ciclo for que puse para contar las veces que se ingresa el usuario?

Comment: Es decir, ese for no cuenta cuantas veces intenta ingresar el usuario, cuenta cuantos usuarios hay con menor index en la lista del usuario ingresado. Si quieres contar cuantas veces intento ingresar el usuario y fracaso, puedes simplemente agregar un contador global y sumarle 1 en la funcion del onclick